# Remove whitespace from output where placeholder arguments not given

Tags: java, string, messageformat

```
String str = "My name is {0} {1} {2}."

String st = MessageFormat.format(str, "Peter", "", "Maxwell");
```

So basically, what this print is :

> *My name is Peter (whitespace) Maxwell.*

Let's say, If my string has got multiple placeholders and if I pass a blank
argument, in that case the output adds up whitespace for that blank argument.

```
So, in our previous case, the output should be like:
```

> **My name is Peter Maxwell.** (No extra whitespace between Peter and Maxwell)

Scenario 2:

String st = MessageFormat.format(str, "Peter", "Branson", "");

```
Actual:
**My name is Peter Branson (whitespace).**

Expected:
**My name is Peter Branson.**
```

> What I want to achieve is, for every unsupplied placeholder argument
> the whitespace should not be part of the final output.
>
> Would appreciate the response !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a *regular expression* to replace multiple white space characters with a single one. Like,

```
String st = MessageFormat.format(str, "Peter", "", "Maxwell")
        .replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

**or** to handle the second case as well

```
String st = MessageFormat.format(str, "Peter", "", "Maxwell")
        .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
        .replaceAll("\\s+\\.", ".");
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
My name is Peter Maxwell.
```

with no other changes

Comment: Why have we used replaceAll() twice in the second case? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @mindfreak The first `replaceAll()` handles scenario 1. The second handles scenario 2. You could also use different `MessageFormat` strings based on the lengths of the three input strings.